# The fastest way to make list of sub-dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have large volume data.

It contains 10 years date variable(about 3,650 days) and there are more than 10,000 observation per each day.

So, total rows are 36,500,000.

My goal is to make multiple(about 3,650) sub-dataframe grouped by date and put it into a single list.

The way I'd use is `for-loop` and It takes a lot of time.

Actually, it take about 1 hour to finish this job under my computer specifications.

I would like to find the best(fastest) way to create multiple sub-dataframe and put it into the list.

My code and simple example are as below.

Thanks for reading.

```
import pandas as pd


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['20200701','20200701','20200702','20200702','20200703'],
                   'city' : ['NewYork', 'Tokyo', 'NewYork', 'Tokyo', 'Moscow'],
                   'amt' : [1,2,10,20,100]})

dfs1 = []

array = df.values
for each in np.unique(array[:,0]):
    dfs1.append(pd.DataFrame(array[array[:,0] == each,:]).rename(columns = {0 : 'date', 1: 'city', 2 : 'amt'}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas groupby is made for this.

```
dfs1 = [x[1] for x in df.groupby('date').__iter__()]
```

Answer (score 1):

For faster iterations you can try out parallel execution although the simpler way to do this is list comprehension

```
[df[df.date==i] for i in df.date.unique()]
```